# global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. react-native-animated v2

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I using `'worklet';` and `runOnUI()` and then get the error below.

Because I use `'worklet';` I added `import 'react-native-reanimated'`

Because I also use `runOnUI` I added `import {runOnUI} from 'react-native-animated'`

Error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. (In 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit(_f)', 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit' is undefined)
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

Comment: Can confirm this issue. Workarounds mentioned [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1380) and [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1380) don't help.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**:

Besides `runOnUI` also import and use something else from `react-native-reanimated`, for example also add `useSharedValue`:

```js
import { useSharedValue, runOnUI } from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

and use the shared value:

```js
const sharedVal = useSharedValue(0);
```

Now the error will go away.

---

**Long answer** (how I got to the solution):

At first I got the error (`global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function.`) when trying to create a widget:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Example = () => {
  const someWorklet = () => {
    'worklet';
    console.log("Hey I'm running on the UI thread");
  };

  return (<Text>Example</Text>);
};

export default Example;
```

Adding `import 'react-native-reanimated';` helped me to get rid of the error.

Then I wanted to run `someWorklet`. So I added a `runOnJS` (`runOnUI` got me the same results) call. My component now returned:

```js
<View>
  <Text>Worklet: {runOnUI(someWorklet)()}</Text>
</View>
```

and I imported it via `import { runOnUI } from 'react-native-reanimated';`.

Now the same error was back.

Only after I also imported and called `useSharedValue` everything worked as expected. This is my component code which didn't throw the error anymore:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useSharedValue, runOnJS } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const Example = () => {
  const someWorklet = () => {
    'worklet';
    console.log("Hey I'm running on the UI thread");
    return 'World';
  };

  const sharedVal = useSharedValue(0);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello, {runOnJS(someWorklet)()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines in App.tsx and index.js

```
1)import "react-native-reanimated"
2)global.__reanimatedWorkletInit = () => {}
```

Comment: You're overwriting `global.__reanimatedWorkletInit` with an empty function. Might lead to undesired side-effects.